# Javascript hoisting and scoping

Tags: javascript

```
function sayHi(name){
   let result="Hi"+name+a;
   console.log(result)
}

let a=1;
sayHi("Alex")
```

The result of the above code is `Hi Alex1`, so from what I understand is the variable `a` is hoisted, but in JS, only the declaration is hoisted, not the initialisation, so how come the result can use the value of `a`?

Comment: You call sayHi after a got value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the value is set before the operation is called.  Look at the order of these two things:

```
let a=1;
sayHi("Alex")
```

*First* the value of `a` is set to `1`, *then* the function `sayHi` is invoked.  Within that function the value of `a` is used.

Swap the two statements and see a different result:

```js
function sayHi(name){
   let result="Hi"+name+a;
   console.log(result)
}

sayHi("Alex")
let a=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions don't try to access variables until they are **called**, which happens after the `a` variable has had a value assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript works like a waterfall.
This means code will be compiled from the higher level.
The variable `a` is initialized before the function `sayHi` is called:
so you have access to his value.
Check how scope works as well here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

If we go line by line, we save the function `sayHi` but do not call it. It is simply saved in the global memory as a function called `sayHi` with the code to run inside of it.

We then save the variable `a` as `1` in global memory.

Then we actually call the function `sayHi`, running the inner block of code.

For the `result` variable, JavaScipt will look into the local memory for `name` and find it as `"Alex"` as the argument for the name parameter. We then go to `a` in which JavaScipt does the same thing and will look into the local memory, it won't find it. It then goes to global memory in which it will find it as the number `1`.

We can then successfully console the result, being `"HiAlex1"` and end our code.

Hope that helps!